# Breadth-first Search Exercise - AI

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I'm new student of AI and I'm trying to do some exercises before I start programming to understand the logic. However, I'm having a hard time doing the exercises, I want to know if someone can help me with this one (any explanation, where I can find material which can helps are welcome):

Consider Deep Blue can evaluate 200 million positions a
second. Assume at each move, a pawn can go to 2 possible
positions, a rook 14, a knight 8, a bishop 14, a queen 28,
and a king 8. Each side has 8 pawns, 2 rooks, 2 knights, 2
bishops, a queen and a king. Under standard regulations,
each side makes 40 moves within the first 2 hours (or 3
minutes a move on the average)

a) Using the breadth-first search algorithm, how many
levels can Deep Blue evaluate (visit) before each move
(in 3 minutes)?

b) To examine 20 levels in 3 minutes, how many positions Deep Blue needs to evaluate (visit) in a second?

I really appreciate any help. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Assuming you're a student and you're trying to understand a homework question, the best resource is probably your professor or TA.

Comment: Actually I'm studying by my self, I took some exercises in the Internet, this is why I'm asking here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you multiply the number of pieces with their individual potential mobility to get the theoretical branching factor for one side. That is, the number of possible moves at each search level.

Then you raise that figure to the power of the search depth to get the number of total positions to evaluate.

So if for the first search ply (half-move), the branching factor is N, then for a two-ply search the total number of positions is N*N, for three it's N*N*N, and so on.

I'll leave the rest up to you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
`I don't know if I'm right, but this was my answer for question b):
p = 2 x 8 = 16
r = 14 x 2 = 28
k = 8 x 2 = 16
b = 14 x 2 = 28
q = 28 x 1 = 28
k = 8 x 1 = 8
Total = 124 x 2 = 248 x 20 = 4960 position p/ level
1 min = 60 x 3 = 180 seconds
4960/180 = 25.7~ => 28 per seconds`
```